# System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Anyone have any idea how to go about resolving this error? This is happening on my live server, but when i run the project local pc or different server there is no error

> Server Error in '/' Application. Request timed out. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> > [HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Comment: Normally a 0x80004005 code is something with access denied, can you provide the stacktrace and some code?

Comment: peer: this is all what i got (copied everything what was in page) & this is why i got so confused...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue in my environment. When I'm working on dev , or locally no errors. But when I'm working on live environment, it gives me the same issue. I've tried to change the timeout value of IIS in the live server machine , but nothing changed. And the solution down here won't help.

Comment: I see this, too, on a request that should take no more than 1 second. looking for tips on where it can be getting stuck.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I don't know if there's any underlying problem, but to solve the timeout issue you can specify the request timeout (in seconds) in the web.config, like this:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />
```

For context, here's a complete `web.config` with just this setting:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: BTW, this setting is to be written in the `<system.web>` section.

Comment: By the by, this doesn't 'solve' anything. It just arbitrarily lengthens the timeout. A bit like if the local DMV "solved" the problem of long lines stretching out the door by increasing the size of the waiting area.

Comment: @EKW: Whether or not this solves anything depends on the circumstances. If there is no underlying issue with performance and it's just a long running operation that requires more time, then this most definitely does solve the problem. If the OP had asked how to improve performance and provided the details necessary to address such a question, then my answer would have been different.

Comment: You can also limit this down so that the timeout doesn't have to be increased for the entire site.To do this, include <location path="YOUR FILE"></location> around the system.web tags.

Comment: FYI, the default timeout is 110 seconds (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8.)

Answer (score 7):

Open IIS -> click on the your siteName -> configuration Editor 
on the Section, scroll to system.web/httpRuntime. Increase the executionTimeout to the time you think it will take to execute your process...

You can also set it in the web.config like the answer above However in my case it work when I do it from IIS.